# Passing a CGFloat value from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, scrollview, cgfloat

I am using a CGFloat value to set my scrollView's contentSize so that it adjusts dynamically to content populated in my textviews. I determine the heights of each text view and their positions in the viewDidLoad method, but have to set the scrollView height in the viewWillAppear method - otherwise the contentSize isn't correct and the scrollView won't scroll. The problem is, the CGFloat value isn't accessible in the viewWillAppear method.

How can I pass that value between the two methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make private ivar in .m file to use it as cache between methods in you class.

```
@implementation YOUR_CLASS_NAME 
{ 
    CGFloat _height; 
}
```

Comment: Yes! I'm a newbie, so this is really helpful. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: But better to name it with a prefix of your own to avoid masking any unknown private ivar with such a common name as height or _height.

Comment: Anyone have a swift 3 version of this?